# How does Thus Spoke Zarathustra conclude?

Tags: nietzsche, literary-theory

How does Thus Spoke Zarathustra conclude?

> "FELLOW-SUFFERING! FELLOW-SUFFERING WITH THE HIGHER MEN!" he cried
>   out, and his countenance changed into brass. "Well! THAT—hath had its
>   time!
>
> My suffering and my fellow-suffering—what matter about them! Do I then
>   strive after HAPPINESS? I strive after my WORK!
>
> Well! The lion hath come, my children are nigh, Zarathustra hath grown
>   ripe, mine hour hath come:—
>
> This is my morning, my day beginneth: ARISE NOW, ARISE, THOU GREAT
>   NOONTIDE!"—
>
> Thus spake Zarathustra and left his cave, glowing and strong, like a
>   morning sun coming out of gloomy mountains.

Supposing that Nietzsche is equating himself with his prophet Zarathustra, is he then concluding that only his work, and only his work freed from "fellow-suffering", will take him over man?

I'd guess so, but find it confusing, partly because I don't know what Nietzsche thought his "work" was, and partly because I'm struggling to place the text (*Thus Spoke Zarathustra*) under that term. The latter may be because I'm over / under thinking the equation between Zarathustra and the author of his story.

If I'm right, then what about the work of untermensch, are we to mimic his ubermensch?

Comment: There is a brief but useful summary of TSZ and its ending at : https://www.gradesaver.com/thus-spoke-zarathustra/study-guide/summary

Comment: simple, and not what i'd guess at. interesting, tho @GeoffreyThomas

Comment: It's not what I would say in a lecture but I didn't know how much detail or nuance you were looking for. It has served some point if has not been completely useless, and to judge by your response it hasn't. All the best - Geoffrey